# Mirror Ubuntu ISOs

Tags: mirrors

I'm trying to setup an Ubuntu ISO mirror. How could I do this with a tool like rsync or apt-mirror? I have >50GBs of space free and unlimited bandwidth.

Answer (score 2):

That is not how a mirror works.

You need around 1Tb in storage and it is used to duplicate *the actual packages*, and not an Ubuntu ISO. ISOs are offered as a direct download, or through a torrent never through a mirror.

See the official document on how to create a [personal mirror](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror). The last part of the document:

> **Extra Credit: Become an Official Mirror**
>
> If you are at a site with bandwidth to spare, you may want to consider becoming an official Ubuntu Mirror.
>
> Visit: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors to view and add mirror

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, how would I set up a CD mirror?
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors